# How can I use one for loop in javaScript to grab values of two arrays?

Tags: javascript, loops

I am stuck on using a javascript loop inside a function to grab the value of two arrays. There are two empty arrays where they get their data when users fill the respective text fields. I can get data from one array using the for loop function:

```
let myLeeds = []

const ulEl= document.getElementById ('ul-el')


  function render (leads){
     let listItems = ""
    
     for (let i = 0; i < leads.length; ++i){
        listItems += `
          <li>
            <a target = '_blank' href = '${leads[i]}'>${leads[i]}</a>
          </li>
                    `
   }
    ulEl.innerHtml = listItems
   
}
```

However, I try to get the value of two arrays in one loop and then save each respective value in assigned variables. Something if possible like below

```
let myLeeds = []
let myNotes = []

const ulEl= document.getElementById ('ul-el')
*const pEl = document.getElementById ('p-el')*

  

    function render (leads){
         let listItems = ""
         let pItems = ""
         for (let i = 0; i < leads.length; ++i){
            listItems += `
              <li>
                <a target = '_blank' href = '${leads[i]}'>${leads[i]}</a>
              </li>
                        `
            *pItems+= `
              <p>
                ${leads[i]}
              </p>
                        `*
       }
        ulEl.innerHtml = listItems
        *pEl.innerHtml = pItems*
    }
```

Comment: Can you add a working [mcve] using the snippet tool (`[<>]`) in the edit box - adding in input, and expected output - so we can understand the question better?

Comment: What doesn't work about the solution you provided? Also, FWIW, you'll want `innerHTML`  instead of `innerHtml`.